# How to make pprint.pprint understand newline character?

Tags: python, newline, pprint

```
>>> a = '1\n2\n3'
>>> pprint(a)
'1\n2\n3'
```

What i want it for pprint to print out

```
1
2
3
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why are you using `pprint` at all?

Comment: From the [very first sentence of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html): "The pprint module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary Python data structures in a form which can be **used as input to the interpreter**." (emphasis mine) So, no, and what you want defeats the point of that module, use `print` instead.

Comment: The reason is because i dump all collected intormation into a dictionary. The dict looks something like this
    
    `info = {
        'ls' : 'a.txt\nb.txt\nc.txt',
        'pwd': '/a/b/c'
    }`

I wanna have an easy way to to just print the entire dict is a easily readable format.

Comment: Call something like `info['ls'] = info['ls'].splitlines()` before calling `pprint(info)`

Comment: @metatoaster Ahhh That is really cool. How come i never thought of that before. Thanks a lot. That works for me :)

Comment: @lionel319 Based on the comment where you specify the reason, it looks to me like the question actually changes a bit and metatoaster answering your question. Maybe you should update the question with this information?